# redirect to two different pages from a single php page

Tags: php

I have Three different buttons.

First Button should redirect to the Google.com, that too using Header() method.

Second Button should redirect to stackoverfkow.com using other then Header() method.

And finally Third button should redirect to the page which is in my local machine (Path of that file is D:\Work space For Practice\Redirection\HomePage.php).

Please can any one help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>buttons</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=1'" />
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=2'" />
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=3'" />
    </body>
</html>
```

redirector.php:

```
<?php
if($_GET['q'] == 1) {
    header('LOCATION: http://google.com');
} else if ($_GET['q'] == 2) {
    header('LOCATION: http://stackoverflow.com');
} else {
    header('LOCATION: homepage.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Very nice @Mohammad Ali Akbari, But its giving the error as     Notice: /Redirection/Page3.php line 2 - Undefined index:  q
Notice: /Redirection/Page3.php line 6 - Undefined index:  q

Comment: add this line: $_GET['q'] = isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:3;

Comment: Fine now there is no proble in code but instead of showing the content of the page its showing the Redirection path. Why it so...?

Answer (score 2):

you can also write like this..
you should 1st give a name off button like
button.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>buttons</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=1'" name='home' />
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=2'" name='ABC' />
        <input type="button" onclick="document.location='redirector.php?q=3'" name='XYZ' />
    </body>
</html>
```

and your php file is

```
  if(isset($_POST['Home']))
 {?>
    <script>window.location = 'http://google.com';</script>
<?php
}
if(isset($_POST['ABC']))
 {?>
    <script>window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant' use header, because it will call your php file from your browser, and not interpret it.

Do you use a local web server? Then redirect to (for example) "http://localhost/HomePage.php" with Header() method.

Comment: I want to call the PHP function inside that I have to call rediredt to other page.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using header() method for that? you can use javascript function.

```
i.e `getRedirect(this.id)`
```

and put it `onclick` event of your buttons.

where you should check button name or ID..

```
function getRedirect(thisid){
 if(thidid == 'first'){

window.location = 'www.google.com';

}else  if(thidid == 'second'){

window.location = 'www.stackoverflow.com';

}else{
window.location = 'localpath';
}

}
```

This may be what u needed...

Thanks.

Comment: Thanku @Chandresh, But I want to call a PHP function. In side that PHP function the redirection should happen.

Comment: ok..then fine.still no worries.. you can write <script> tags in php function also. and its working fine i think.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code. B'coz I am totally nill in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you php function may look like this.

```
<?php 
function getredirect(btn_value){
   if(btn_value == 'first'){?>
     <script>window.location = 'www.google.com';</script>
<?php }else if(btn_value == 'second'){?>
       <script>window.location = 'www.stackoverflow.com';</script>
<?php }else{ ?>
       <script>window.location = 'your local path';</script>
<?php } ?>
}
?>
```

Thanks..